# Import a remote XML file into MVC 4 Webapp

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webapp that needs to import 3 different remote XML files every night. These files have student and parent information, study information, etc.

Can someone point me to information how to read the XML (via http) and then loop over every student so I can add information from the other XML files and store the relations into my database?

Need some example code like:

- Open & read Parents XML and store in database with fixed Ids from XML file
- Open & read Students XML and store in database AND link to their respective parents using the parent id's from the parent XML
- Also store study information for every student

I need to know what my strategy would be. What would the smartest and most efficient method be to accomplish this using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

First a bit of advice..

There is a caveat when you are using only a webapp, because it won't automatically fetch the updated files. At least not out-of-the-box. A webapp will be unloaded by IIS when it's not used for a long time, and is almost always a "reactive" application.

But... it is possible to schedule a task in which you open a webpage at a certain time each night, and start the import that way.

You could use the System.Net.HttpWebRequest to fetch the xml's to a local temp folder like this:

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://url.to/file.xml") as HttpWebRequest;

// check if the cast went well
if (req != null) {
    try {
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        System.IO.FileStream outFileStream =  
            System.IO.File.Create(@"Path\To\localfile.xml");

        resp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(outFileStream);

        outFileStream.Close();
        outFileStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (ExceptionTypeA ex1) { 
        // Catch all specific exceptions... ommitted here for brevity 
    }
}
```

You can then use XDocument / XElement ( Linq to Xml ) to extract data from the Xml files and use standard ADO.NET API to create and process the DB Import.

Only after the import into a (relational) database you can fully use the entity framework to do the data retrieval / modification. You might even be able to convert all xml data into structured collections of POCO types and use the entity framework to query these collections, but I honestly don't think that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you would use the Entity Framework directly with your XML files. EF is designed to work with relational databases.

I think you will have to import the data into a relational database in some way.

If using SQL Server, you can achieve such an import (given you have downloaded the XML file already with the help of a scheduled task on the web server) using a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx):

```
// Create DataSet and load data
DataSet ParentData = new DataSet();
ParentData.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("ParentFile.xml"));

// Create SqlBulkCopy object
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString");
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "YourParentTable";

// Get DataTable and copy it to database
DataTable ParentTable = ParentData.Tables["Parent"];
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ParentTable);
```